# How to use pipeTo in AKKA correctly

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Hi I have two examples below within the receive method of an actor:

First one does not cache the sender actor for piping

```
val futureV = //Some function call that returns a Future
futureV.pipeTo(sender)
```

Second one takes the sender in a val first

```
val currentS=sender
val futureV = //Some function call that returns a Future
futureV.pipeTo(currentS)
```

My question is which one is the correct way to code and why?

Comment: It only depends when you call sender in a closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same. The sender is not going to change. `pipeTo` takes its argument by value, not by name.