# Akka: send back response to Actor

Tags: scala, akka, slick

I have the following code that sends back a response to the sender Actor (the responding actor loads a list from a table using Slick):

```
class ManageUsersData extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case _       => {
      sender ! loadUsers
    }
  }


  def loadUsers =  {

    var list = new ListBuffer[String]()
    val db = Database.forConfig("dbconfig")
    try {

      val users: TableQuery[Users] = TableQuery[Users]
      val future = db.run(users.result)


      future onComplete {
        case Success(u) => u.foreach {
          user => {
            list += user.firstName
          }
          list
        }
        case Failure(t) => println("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
      }

    } finally db.close

   list

  }
}
```

The problem here is that `loadUsers` returns before waiting for the Future to complete. How can this be approached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [pipe pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html#Use_With_Actors):

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

// ...

def receive = {
  val originalSender = sender
  loadUsers pipeTo originalSender
}
```

Comment: why are you importing pipe if you're using pipeTo ?

Comment: This is how it's defined in the docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html#Use_With_Actors

Comment: The class doesn't compile, do I need to touch `loadUsers` to return a future?

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860498 says you do not need to capture the sender before you provide it to `pipeTo`.

Answer (score 3):

The conceptual solution is already mentioned by Jean Logeart. Regarding loadUsers, I think this is a shorter version?

```
def loadUsers =  {

    val db = Database.forConfig("dbconfig")
    try {

      val users: TableQuery[Users] = TableQuery[Users]
      db.run(users.result).map(_.firstName)

    } catch {
      case e: Exception => println("An error has occured: " + e.getMessage)
    } finally db.close

 }
```

Comment: The solution is given by you. I wanted to optimize the method he defined. Will add the comment.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, the easiest approach would be to simply send the `future` back to the `sender`, instead of the *async-filled* `list`.

As in

```
  def loadUsers =  {

    val db = Database.forConfig("dbconfig")
    try {

      val users: TableQuery[Users] = TableQuery[Users]
      
      val future = db.run(users.result)

      future.map {     //the future
        _.map {        //the returning Seq
          _.firstName 
        }
      }

    } finally db.close

  }
```

Now the caller actor has the burden to handle the future or the failure.

This also has the drawback that, if the `sender` used the `ask`/`?` operation, the async result will be a `Future` wrapping a further `Future`.

You can overcome this issue by using the `pipeTo` method, which sends a future message to the caller without needing to bother about unwrapping it.

The downside of *piping* the result is that the `sender` should have a way to identify which reply belongs to which request. A possible solution is to send a request identifier that will be sent back with the answer, so the requesting actor can easily link the twos.

#### sidenote

Why would you map on the `firstName` attribute in the future result instead of using a projection within the slick query? I assume it's for the sake of keeping the example simple.